# iOS / Objective-C: NSNotification

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotification

I´ve got a question based on the NSNotification in Objective-C:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                      selector:@selector(method:)
                                      name:@"SOME_STRING"
                                      object:nil];
```

I really don´t know how to set the object attribute...

So, if I only want to recieve notifications from class a, how can I set it to class a?

```
[A class]
```

and

```
[A alloc]
```

dosen´t work.

I´m very confused about the object parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `nil`, then you get all `@"SOME_STRING"` notifications sent.

if not `nil`, you get only those which pertain to the instance passed to `object`.

so... it's not really an association "from class a", it's an association to a specific instance. when the instances match (observe and post), you are notified.

With that information, you could use the objc instance returned by `[A class]` as the `object` parameter in order to receive the notifications you are interested in -- it looks like this:

**Observe:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                      selector:@selector(method:)
                                      name:@"SOME_STRING"
                                      object:[A class]];
                                              ^^^^^^^
```

**Post:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  postNotificationName:@"SOME_STRING" object:[A class]];
                                              ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: ah thanks.. i thought it´s for all objects of thaht calss, but it´s only for a instance.

Answer (score 2):

The object parameter is the object you want to observe, you can't observe a class.

But in your method you can check object class:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                      selector:@selector(method:)
                                      name:@"SOME_STRING"
                                      object:nil];

- (void)method:(NSNotification*)notif
{
    if ([[notif object] isKindOfClass:[A class]]) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: filtering on the receiving end is not necessary or ideal.

Comment: i don´t want to do that, i was only wondering about that parameter

Answer (score 0):

For Post a Notification you can use below method :-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"testNotification" object:[A class]];
```

To Receive a Notification first add below method in your viewDidLoad method :-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notifyWhenCalled:) name:@"testNotification" object:[A class]];
```

Declare below selector. This will called when your notification is fired :-

```
- (void) notifyWhenCalled:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  if ([[notification object] isKindOfClass:[A class]]) 
  {
    //..... Write your code to do anything.
  }
}
```